# Getting blank {} response after create new version of an existing API in wso2 APIM 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have create a new version of an existing API in wso2 APIM 3.2.0. When I try to invoke that API I am getting blank response like {}.
Version 1 is working fine, but when we triggered V2 we are getting empty response.
I could also see that new version of the API is not getting created under synapse-config/api folder

Comment: There aren't enough details to answer your question. I would suggest enabling Wire Logs and see what's going on. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/#enable-gateway-wire-logs

Comment: Did you see any errors in the carbon logs when you create the new version?

Comment: Is this happening for all of your APIs or only for one specific API? Are you able to try this for another API and update with the result along with any other error information you are seeing?